# Pygame buttons not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have created some sort of menu navigation system in my game. All the screens are blitted in. The "Play" and "Quit" and "Controls" button works just fine but when I try to press menu from the controls screen, nothing happens. On the controls screen, you can faintly see the first menu screen from before. That might be the problem. I think that as the return to menu button is over the previous controls page button, it somehow is pressing the controls button from before. The button and menu segment of my code will be pasted here and the full thing will be pasted in a pastebin.

```
def text_to_button(msg,color,buttonx,buttony,buttonwidth,buttonheight,size = "small"):
textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
textRect.center = ((buttonx + buttonwidth/2)), buttony+(buttonheight/2)
gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def button(text,x,y,width,height,inactive_color,active_color,size = "small",action = None):
cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
#print(click)
if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color,(x,y,width,height))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        if action == "quit":
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if action == "controls":
            game_controls()

        if action == "play":
            gameLoop()
        if action == "main":
            game_intro()

else:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color,(x,y,width,height))
text_to_button(text,black,x,y,width,height,size)

def game_controls():
gcont = True
while gcont:
    gameDisplay.blit(cont,(0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()


    button("Play",150,500,100,50,white,gray,"small",action = "play")
    button("Main Menu",320,500,150,50,white,gray,"tiny", action = "main")
    button("Quit",550,500,100,50,white,gray,"small", action = "quit")


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

def game_intro():
intro = True
while intro:

    gameDisplay.blit(imggg,(0,0))

    button("Play",150,500,100,50,white,gray,"small",action = "play")
    button("ControLs",320,500,150,50,white,gray,"tiny", action = "controls")
    button("Quit",550,500,100,50,white,gray,"small", action = "quit")







    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:
            intro = False
```

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/jrd82gkJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have very hard time to debug your code in order to achieve the behavior you want for one simple reason:

The logic you use to switch between different screens providing different functionality is causing much trouble you can't directly see if you only run the game.

So you think: "oh ... how come the button doesn't work, there must be an issue with the button".

You are probably not aware of the fact that using functions having own while loops you go deeper and deeper into recursive calls with increasing recursion depth with each switch from one view to another - it is not how pygame is thought to be programmed.

I suggest you add some `print()` commands into your code to see in the console output that the code doesn't really do what you expect even if it appears to be OK at the first glance because it works.

Then I suggest you REWRITE your entire code so that you have one main `while notGameExit:` loop, and don't use any other looping in the helper functions. If you want use looping in your helper functions at least don't call from the helper functions another functions with own loops (and so on), but RETURN from them with an explicit `return` to avoid recursion.

If you leave the in the main loop called function with return your main loop will continue running and depending on some switches you can display in it different things on the screen and react differently to user actions.

Maybe looking at a minimal working pygame script showing "action" without usage of a loop you will gain better understanding and some deep "enlightenment" about how pygame works and then start a total rewrite of your game using another approach as this one you have used in the current code? Then come back with what you have achieved if you have further questions, but you won't probably have any, because it would be much easier to debug it yourself if the code will become more straightforward.

```
import pygame

pygame.init() # start PyGame (necessary because 'import pygame' doesn't start PyGame)
winDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768)) # set PyGame window size to 1024x768 pixel

pygame.display.set_caption("Minimal PyGame Test Script")
# Time in pygame is measured in milliseconds (1/1000 seconds) (defined by TIMER_RESOLUTION constant):
pygame.TIMER_RESOLUTION = 1000 # assure 1000 explicit, don't relay on default value 

colorWhite = (255, 255, 255) # RGB color in Pygame format (valueRed=255, valueGreen=255, valueBlue=255)
colorRed   = (255,   0,   0)
colorGreen = (  0, 255,   0)
colorBlue  = (  0,   0, 255)

winDisplay.fill(colorWhite)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(3000) # show the Pygame window for 3 seconds
winDisplay.fill(colorRed)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(3000) # show the Pygame window for 3 seconds
winDisplay.fill(colorGreen)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(3000) # show the Pygame window for 3 seconds
winDisplay.fill(colorBlue)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(3000) # show the Pygame window for 3 seconds
winDisplay.fill(colorWhite)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(3000) # show the Pygame window for 3 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still kind of new to coding, started 2 months ago. I have found out why it hasn't been working. I have got it to work but I sometimes have to press the button two or even three times to work. I'm trying to debug the code right now

Comment: You are welcome. The strange behavior comes from random timing of recursive calls which happen on button press (therefore sometimes, two or three times, just RANDOM). It "appears" to work properly, but if you switch your views often enough you will run into "exceeding recursion depth" error (won't probably happen in practice - you will get tired of switching the views before).